# how to call function from component that is independent of each other

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components, one parent component which renders 2 child components. I need to access the function of the 1st child component from the 2nd child component.

Sample Code:

**Parent Component:**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
myRef: React.RefObject<any>;
constructor(props: any) {
super(props);
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
  return (
    <div>
      {/* some code */}
      <ChildOne />
      <ChildTwo />
    </div>
  );
```

**ChildOne:**

```
function ChildOne() {
  const childOneFunction = () => {
    console.log("Hello from child one");
  };

  return <div>{/* some code */}</div>;
}
}
```

**ChildTwo:**

```
function ChildTwo() {
  useEffect(() => {
    childOneFunction();
  });

  return <div>{/* some code */}</div>;
}
```

I need call the `childOneFunction()` from childTwo component. Is it possible without any 3rd party library like redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) and [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle).

Demo:

```
let ChildOne = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    childOneFunction: () => {
      console.log('Hello from child one');
    },
  }));

  return <div>1</div>;
});

let ChildTwo = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        ref.current.childOneFunction();
      }}
    >
      2
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const test = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildOne ref={test} />
      <ChildTwo ref={test} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: My parent function is a class-component with typescript enabled. It show `type '{ myRef: RefObject<any> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
  Property 'myRef' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.`

I have edited the parent code, to be more clear

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas I am not familiar with typescript, I showed you approach, that you will have to figure out yourself I am afraid.